# Subversion hooks location

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-hooks

I have inherited a subversion project and I know it has post commit hooks for when anything is committed to `trunk` but I am having problems locating these hooks. Is they any sure fire way of find svn hooks?

I have looked across the repo for `#!/bin/sh` and `*.tmpl` but with no success. I have also looked in `TortoiseSVN > Settings > Hook Scripts` but it's empty :(. To further complicate the matter the original author was know for his unconventional approach :( x 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server-side hooks (because there are also client-side in TortoiseSVN):

1. Placed at server's side (you must to have shell or physical access to the whole server) in `/FULL/PATH/TO/REPO/hooks` directory
2. Outside the repository tree (you can't get it with checkout)
3. Have *predefined names*

   - start-commit
   - pre-commit
   - pre-revprop-change
   - pre-lock
   - pre-unlock
   - post-commit
   - post-lock
   - post-unlock
   - post-revprop-change

but *custom content*

Comment: I'll ssh in and have a look